# JQuery BGStretcher and sticky footer not working

Tags: jquery, sticky-footer

I'm trying to use JQuery BGStretcher and a sticky footer setup and while they work on their own fine, they somehow conflict and cancel each other out when put together in a page.

you can see it here: http://www.designosaur.net/htmltest/

(using latest BGStretcher version 2.0.1 + JQuery 1.7.1, used the technique from this page here for the sticky footer: http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer.htm )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.bgstretcher-area { text-align: left; height:100% }
.bgstretcher-page { height:100% }
```

Use the above css, it should do the trick.